# Checking if any value in Column is equal to Todays Date

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm working in Google Sheets and I am trying to determine if any value of dates listed in the column is equal to Today's Date.

I have tried using the `COUNTIF` formula the `ISDATE` formula and the `IF` formula against the value of `TODAY()` and nothing seems to be working right.

```
=IF('Invoices-Quickbooks-Data'!L:L,ISDATE(TODAY()),true)
```

This formula actually works the best for me.  I would expect it to calculate if any of the values equal Today's Date.  Ironically this tells me that the answer is `TRUE` even when none of the dates actually match Today's date so I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason why your formula is always returning true is because `ISDATE(TODAY())` will always return true (when is today *not* a date?) and furthermore, you can't use an IF statement like that to query a whole column. The first argument to IF is a condition, and a column range is not a condition.

To apply a function over a range, you want to use an [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275). Here is how you would check a range of cells to see if any value in the column (or range) contains a date equal to today:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(A:A)=TODAY(),FALSE)),1,FALSE),FALSE)
```

Just replace A:A with the range you want to check. The return of an ArrayFormula is an array, which  is why I have to use VLOOKUP to check for any TRUE values inside it.

[image: Screenshot]

---

#### Advanced solution:

A really cool feature in sheets is the [query() function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343), which essentially lets you run a SQL-like query over a range of cells. I like it because it makes formulaes very readable - for example, the entire ARRAYFORMULA solution above can be replaced with:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY('Invoices-Quickbooks-Data'!L:L,"select count(L) where dateDiff(L,now()) = 0 label count(L) ''",-1) > 0,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check it with just simple `IF` formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), IF(A2:A=TODAY(), TRUE), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A=TODAY(), TRUE, ))
```

[image: 0]